# Convergence/divergence of a given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be the series of term $a_n=\dfrac{(2^a)^n}{n^b}$. I am trying to prove that for $a<0$ and $b>0$, the series converges, and that for $a>0$, $b>0$, the series diverges.

For the first case, I know that $\dfrac{(2^a)^n}{n^b}\leq \dfrac{1}{(2^{-a})^n}$

The last term is the term of a geometric series which converges so, by the comparison test, I can affirm that the original series converges.

Now, if $a>0$, $b>0$ I am not so sure how to show divergence, the idea is to show that $(2^a)^n$ goes "faster" to $\infty$ than $\dfrac{1}{n^b}$ goes to $0$. I would appreciate some help with this part.

Comment: Using the Root test or Ratio test might be easiest.

Comment: The ratio test worked, thanks!

Comment: Show that if $a,b>0$ then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2^a)^n}{n^b}\neq 0$ then the series diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $a, b > 0$, apply ratio test with $c = 2^a > 1$ since $a > 0$. So:$a_n = \dfrac{c^n}{n^b}$. Then:
$|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \dfrac{c^{n+1}}{(n+1)^b}\cdot \dfrac{n^b}{c^n} = c\cdot \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^b \to c > 1$ when $n \to \infty$. So the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint try appling [Cauchy condensation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to simplify the general term of series.

Comment: I'll try to solve it by this theorem but I think the Ratio test is simpler, thanks

Comment: Actually if you use Cauchy Condensation, you get back the same series.

Comment: @Nameless Yeah, my first feeling about using this theorem was different.